# How can I connect to the server which has the Azure sql database without prompting a password

Tags: azure, security, ssh, azure-sql-database, azure-container-instances

I have an azure container instance and an azure sql database.

I would like to connect the azure container instance to the server which runs the database because I need to tune some params for postgres.

I want to do this programatically without prompting for a password but without compromising the security.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Managed Service Identity(MSI) with ACI, configure Azure SQL to use Azure AD and authorize identity to your database.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-managed-identity
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql